# iOS + Bluetooth - How to do?

Tags: ios, bluetooth

I'm new on iOS development, I have a couple of questions about a project that I need to do.

First of all, my problem is about to create a single hardware with a Bluetooth device and it will send information for any iOS device or android connected to it with Bluetooth... so here are my questions:

1) What kind of Bluetooth hardware I will need? A BLE 4.0? Or i can use a normal one that communicates with 2.1 and 3.0 devices? I need to guarantee that iPhone 4S and later versions will work and this won't cause any trouble with the android communication.

2) What would i need for development? I have a MacBook pro, do I need an adapter to use the ble 4.0 of iOS 5 simulator? Or the Bluetooth of the mac can handle it?

3) Is it possible to my hardware send information for the older and the newest version of iOS?

Sorry for any stupid question, i only started developing a few days ago..

Thank you all!

Answer (score 2):

1) This is a pretty broad question. You probably do want to use Bluetooth 4.0. iOS devices can talk to Bluetooth 2.1 devices, but in order to access them in an app you develop, you have to be a member of Apple's Made for iPhone program. Getting into the Made For iPhone program is far from trivial, and unless you're a company with real experience, you won't be able to. You can develop apps that communicate with Bluetooth 4.0 (aka Bluetooth LE) without restrictions.

2) It depends on how new your MacBook Pro is. Off the top of my head, the mid-2012 MacBook Pro, and MacBook Airs are the first/only MacBooks to include Bluetooth 4.0. The iOS simulator *can* be used to develop Bluetooth 4.0-capable apps on these machines. If your MacBook Pro is older, I'm not sure about the options for adding Bluetooth 4.0 capability via an adapter. I think you're best off doing your development and testing on a real iOS device anyway.

EDIT: I've learned more since I originally answered this question. Even on a Mac with built in Bluetooth 4.0 you will need an external Bluetooth 4.0 adapter to test a BT 4.0 application in the iOS simulator, as explained in [Technical Note TN2295](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2295/_index.html).

3) I'm really not sure what you're asking here. Use of CoreBluetooth.framework and Bluetooth 4.0 requires an iPhone 4S, iPad 3, 5th gen iPod Touch or later, running iOS 5.0 or later. For most new development, my advice is to just target iOS 6.1 and above. iOS 6.0 adds some nice additional functionality to CoreBluetooth.

Comment: Thank you so much for the awnser! On my hardware i will use a bluetooth 4.0 le with dual mode, so i will be able to connect with other devices that are not 4.0, like most of android's.
My real problem now is that my MacBook have no blutooth 4.0 so i will need to only test on iphone 4s/5 and not on simulator...